# Add flag to UnityWebRequest

Tags: rest, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a POST request to webpage that expects the `--data` field to be filled with some data to be processed. I'm pretty much trying to recreate this `curl` request, but with `UnityWebRequest`.

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/clic/say?text=Make+the+gene+set  --data '{"geneSetMembers":["UST"],"geneSetName":"selection0"}'
```

The UnityWebRequest documentation mentions that GET requests don't set any flags other than the url, but it's not clear if no other custom options exist for posts. Is there some way to format a WWWform or something that will hold the data such that the server will recognize it?

```c#
var form = new WWWForm();
// some way to plug in the jsonified data to the form
webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(url + route + to_say, form);
webRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
webRequest.SendWebRequest();
// etc etc
```

I've tried just giving the form a field named "data" a la

```c#
form.AddField("data", "{ \"geneSetMembers\":[\"UST\"],\"geneSetName\":\"selection0\"}");
```

but the server does not like it, saying it "got error Invalid JSON literal name: data" So clearly that's the wrong syntax for it

EDIT: put lines in the same order they were in original code. Sorry, I have commented lines between them

Comment: Well what you tried with `AddField` looks nothing close to what you added as data via `curl` where you passed a valid json: `{"geneSetMembers":["UST"],"geneSetName":"selection0"}`

Comment: Surely you at least needed 2 fields geneSetMembers and genSetName ?

Comment: I tried a variety of setups for the json part, including "{geneSetMembers:[\"UST\", \"SAMD5\", \"PLAGL1\", \"SLC35D3\", \"SAMD3\", \"TMEM200A\", \"TRDN\"], geneSetName: \"selection0\"}" but the error is thrown on the field being called "data" so I wasn't paying attention to which particular attempt at a json was connected to my copy/pasted line

Comment: Could you show the PHP code?

Comment: Edited post to put lines in the right dang order. The PHP error code was HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. The server itself is running a weird LISP system that I think would only complicate things

Comment: Well the problem is that you can't really use `AddField` since the field is not called `data`. The option `--data` or also just `-d` is not a field bit the entire data section for this curl request ... Depends what kind of data section the server expects .. maybe you need something that is not a field ..

Comment: Yeah, my hope was someone would know where to look to fill in the data section in a similar way to how webRequest.SetRequestHeader() fills in that part of the request

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server doesn't like to receive the data as a field called `data`.

This ofcourse depends totally on the PHP code we don't see since you didn't share that part. b

But at least I can tell you that `--data` or also simply `-d` in `curl` refer to the entire data section and is not a field called `data`.

---

You could try to instead use a [`MultiPartFormDataSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormDataSection-ctor.html) passing just the data itself without a specific field name

```c#
var data = "{\"geneSetMembers\":[\"UST\"],\"geneSetName\":\"selection0\"}";
var form = new List<IMultiFormPart>{ new MultiPartFormDataSection(data) };
webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(url + route + to_say, form);
yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

which is now sent as content-type `multipart/form-data` though ...

---

Another alternative if your server really needs to receive a content-type `application/json` might be to "manually" compose the request e.g. like

```c#
var data = "{\"geneSetMembers\":[\"UST\"],\"geneSetName\":\"selection0\"}";
var request = new UnityWebRequest(url + route + to_say, "POST");
var bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
yield return request.SendWebRequest();
```

---

Though of you look close now this seems actually not to be the case since if you read the [man `curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

which is actually exactly the default content type used by the simple `string` version of `UnityWebRequest.Post`.

So thinking about it it should actually be as simple as using the pure `string` version of [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html):

```c#
var data = "{\"geneSetMembers\":[\"UST\"],\"geneSetName\":\"selection0\"}";
var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url + route + to_say, data);
yield return request.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: I haven't tried the Bytes versions yet (will probably get back to this problem Wednesday). But I have tried gong for just the string as in the last example. The server side errors out with "got error Invalid char on JSON input: `%'" which is just a 500 error on the Unity side. That happens for all strings I've passed that way, including the empty string and "{}"

Comment: This sounds like your server doesn't like a URL encoded string. By default Unity automatically URL encodes the given string .. in this case you should definitely try the byte version.